# Can a pressure wave induce pressure in a liquid it's propagating through?

Tags: acoustics, fluid-statics

I have a piece of cylindrical plastic container containing a liquid and sealed at all ends. The bottom seal is a flexible material that can be broken with enough force. The question is then is: can I induce pressure in the liquid contained, enough to break the seal and cause the fluid to ooz out, by beaming at the container a pressure wave of certain properties. In the event the above is feasible, what properties and orientation of pressure wave will achieve it, and how can I calculate the amount of pressure induced or amount of force on the flexible seal.

Comment: Of course it is feasible. That's why the shock wave from an explosion can break windows hundreds of meters away. To calculate what is going to happen you need to understand how pressure waves are transmitted and reflected when the impedance of the medium changes, and that needs a textbook on acoustics, not a short answer on SE.

Comment: @ alephzero. Can you further help with a web link or textbook reference on this acoustics you talk of, and I'll really love if you could, given certain conditions, just provide a model of pressure as a function of some properties of a sound wave (like frequency, amplitude, and/or wavelength)?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, as  alephzero said. However there is no straightforward, analytic calculation to find the "shape" of the wave. The only way to solve this problem is probably through a computer simulation or through experimentation.